# Was ist das (der?) Effeff?

Tags: etymology, noun, meaning

Was ist das (der?) Effeff im folgenden Satz?

> Das müsst ihr aus dem Effeff können!

Comment: it is "das Effeff" btw.

Comment: @ladybug: How did you find that? Is it because letters always are neutral?

Comment: To be honest I just followed my instinct as a native speaker. ^^ But you're probably right, it is "das F" (like "das A", "das Ypsilon", "das Ess-Zett" etc.),  so I guess all letters are neutral.

Comment: Given that the “Effeff” only appears in “aus dem Effeff”, it’s hard to really define that. But I would agree with “das Effeff”, it’s what my feelings tell me :)

Comment: Unsicher: Assimilation nach Französisch *effet* /e'fe:/, wie im Ballsport ein angedrehter Ball, so vielleicht eine Bewegung aus dem Handgelenk. Soweit *effet* von *effect* kommt (das ist *Fakt*) bleibt anzumerken das partizip perfekt zu *facio* einst durch Reduplizierung wie in *fhefhaket* gebildet wurde, welches aber insgesamt verloren ging. Vielleicht lebt es doch in dem Effeff weiter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Es bedeutet „etwas hervorragend zu beherrschen oder zu verstehen“, quasi „wie im Schlaf beherrschen“.

Zum Beispiel:

> Ein Verkäufer muss sein Handwerk aus dem Effeff beherrschen.

Das heißt, er darf nicht lange überlegen, muss instinktiv das Richtige tun.

Die Herkunft des Begriffs ist laut Duden-Wörterbuch ungeklärt. Vielleicht stammt sie aus der kaufmannssprachlichen Abkürzung *ff* = „sehr fein“.

Die Fernsehsendung „Wissen macht Ah!“ für Kinder hat einen schönen Artikel über die Redewendung: [KuriosAh! Wann beherrscht man etwas aus dem Effeff?](http://www.wdr.de/tv/wissenmachtah/bibliothek/effeff.php5)

Comment: Und die haben eine *ganz* andere Herleitung, die niemand hier erwähnte, die aber recht überzeugend klingt (besser als "feinfein" oder sowas).  Leider keine Quelle dafür.

Comment: AFAIK war ff eine Verballhornung des griechischen Buchstabens Pi und wurde despektierlich für akademisches Wissen verwendet.

Answer (score 10):

"*Etwas aus dem Effeff können*" means "to be able to do something blindfolded", that is, to do it really well and almost by reflexes. There does not seem to be a consensus on what *Effeff* actually means. The [German Wikipedia article on Effeff](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effeff_%28Redewendung%29) lists the following theories:

- *ff* comes from *folgende Seiten*.
- *ff* comes from *sehr fein* (two *fein*).
- *ff* comes from Latin *ex forma, ex functione*.